# Why don’t we need for loop to print strings in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, printf, size

I don't understand Why don’t we have to print  strings in for loop ? In normal cases we need to print arrays in for loop. For example, if we want to print the array of integers. It will be like this:

```
int a[n];

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%d", a[i]);
}
```

But for strings like:

```
char s[100] = " Hello ";
printf("%s\n", s);
```

it is enough to write the name of array.
EDIT: It seems like I didnt ask my question properly as some of you wrote answers which is not related to my question.I edit my question.

Comment: Because strings in C are terminated with a special character `'\0'` which is letting the program to know where it ends.

Comment: Any decent beginner tutorial should cover this. Maybe you need a better book/source or whatever resource you are using.

Comment: Like the others have said. You should be able to type 'man 3 printf' if you're in a linux system to read in-depth about printf (and its related functions). Or, alternatively [you can read about it here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

Comment: You surely can do so, as many provided examples below. Calling printf has a cost. The cost lies within the printf itself. Thus, it's good to just call printf as minimal as possible. You can try printing a large string char by char and together, and then compare thier speed.

Comment: There is still a loop but it's inside `printf()`.

Comment: Thank you guys for explanation I get it know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is far from analogous.  `%d` refers to a *single* integer, while `%s` refers to an entire (but still single) string.

You are not passing the size of the array `n[]` to `printf` either - rather you are calling `printf` `n` times.  You are printing one `int` just as you are printing one string.

The actual string length is not known *a priori*, rather `printf` iterates the string until it encounters the `\0` terminator.  Equivalent to:

```
for( int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    printf( "%c", s[i] ) ;
}
```

because

```
char s[100] = " Hello ";
```

is equivalent to:

```
char s[100] = { ' ', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', '\0' } ;
```

Comment: @subhanceo you are welcome, though the answer makes less sense since you changed the question somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

Strings terminate with the empty character `'\0'`, that's how it is possible to know when a string ends even without explicitly passing its length.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that C-style strings (which are char arrays) are zero-terminated, whereas int arrays are normally not zero terminated.

Theoretically, you could also create an int array which is zero-terminated and print that in a loop:

```
int a[] = {5,7,3,0};

for (i=0;a[i]!=0;i++)
{
   printf("%d",a[i])
}
```

However, the problem with zero-terminated int arrays is that the number 0 could be a meaningful value, so you cannot be sure that it really is the end of the array when you encounter that value. With strings, however, the [ASCII-Code](http://www.asciitable.com/) 0 does not represent a meaningful value, so you can be reasonably sure that you have reached the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are multiple characters all at once. You cannot ask for a specific character from a string. If you want to do so, you must refer to it as an array of chars like this

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
     printf("%c", s[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are already providing the parameter which is "%s" to the printf function which already has a definition telling it how to print a string.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason is that char only takes 1 byte of memeory and when you just press a character, the first index of array is filled up completely and it moves on to the next one till it encounters NULL character. This is not the case with integer array where the size is more than 1 byte and is machine dependent. So you cannot escape the first index by just pressing the number less than the maximum range. If you try to do this, it will store your numbers in first index only and hence a for loop is required there.